# Custom View does not fill whole screen

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to fill my custom view on whole screen. i used weight but still not working.
I am using following code. please some one tell me solution.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/LinearLayout2"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/back"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<com.alarm_animation.CustomeView
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="#ffffff" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use match_parent not wrap_content on your custom view.

Remove layout_weight. It is not needed in this situation.

Comment: I already tried it its not working but it still leaving spaces on four sides

Comment: Then you should also remove the padding on your linearlayout.

Comment: Removing the padding allows the child control to fill all available space.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting up your custom view like this.-

```
<com.alarm_animation.CustomeView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#ffffff" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Alter you layout file like this

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/back"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <com.alarm_animation.CustomeView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#ffffff" />
```

Comment: Maybe its you custom view not scaling well. But this is all you can du in the xml layout

Comment: Have you remove the margin in the linearlayout??

Comment: Actually my custom view is leaving spaces on four sides. i want to remove those spaces

Comment: Share or look in the code of your customview to se if there is some kind of margin around. If its a standard then try to remove if by setting the layout_margin to 0dp.

Comment: Also if you are adding this layout to another then look at that layout for any margins.

Comment: It can also be padding :)